# Is it possible to replace the memory allocator in a debug build of an MFC application?

Tags: memory-management, mfc, allocator

I'd like to make use of [Electric Fence](http://code.google.com/p/electric-fence-win32/) in an MFC application. I'd like to track `new`/ `delete`, and if I can track `malloc`/ `free` that's an added bonus.

Unfortunately, MFC redefines `new` and `delete` - but using macros (DEBUG_NEW) - so I can't use the standard C++ method of redefining them. (MFC defines them to have different signatures, with source file and line numbers as additional parameters).

Is there any way to force all `new`/ `delete`s to go via my allocator, and stop MFC trying to grab these allocators?

Comment: Why can't you define your own DEBUG_NEW macro and use it instead of MFCs?

Comment: It seems no matter how hard I try to get all the macros, there is still code in the bowels of MFC that will try to use the debug allocator.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project I'm on takes approx. 30 mins to compile, so each little tweak to the main headers wastes a large part of my day. I'll try some more changes tonight and leave it building overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the MFC hooking of new by redefining  DEBUG_NEW in the end of stdafx.h

```
#undef DEBUG_NEW
#define DEBUG_NEW new
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that - I couldn't seem to eliminate all of them. Some of them seem to be controlled by _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT, which it isn't possible to change. I've found that some always seem to slip through.

Comment: Marking as correct answer as I think the problem I'm having is specific to our app.